# How do you test a mutable, implied result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, pytest, mutable

I have a function that doesn't "return" anything but relies on altering a dictionary/list using its mutability.
i.e.:

```
def func(my_list):
    my_list.append(4)
```

I want to test this function using pytest and parameterisation:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input1, result", [
    ([1], [1, 4]),
    ([33, 44], [33,44, 4])
])
def test_mytest(input1, result):
    assert func(input1) == result
```

Problem is, this obviously won't work because my function doesn't actually "return" `my_list`.
Is it possible to test the value of `my_list` using pytest, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the value of list1 to result `after` the call to the function.

```
def test_mytest(input1):
    func(input1)
    assert input1 == result
```

Note that input1 will be modified after the call to the function and can now be compared to the expected result

Comment: Thanks. I could have sworn I tested that already and it didn't work. But actually it does!

Comment: You could also do `copy.copy` (or `copy.deepcopy` depending on what the elements of the list will be) on `input1`, before mutating it with `func`, so that whatever is passed in as `input1` won't be mutated in the parent scope.